# Get the formatted value of a cell for using with left-right-function

Tags: excel-formula

I am facing a problem currently in Excel.

I want to extract the last 3 characters of a cell. This is not problem at all because there is the function "right" which does it exactly the job.

But the problem is, that it only uses the value ifself, not the formatted value.

For example, the value is 1234.56 and the formatted value is "1234.56 EUR". The function right results in "4.56" when returning the last 3 characters. This is not what I want, i want to extract the "EUR".

So how it is possible to convert a cell-formatted-value into a "string" which can then be used for the left-function to extract "EUR" in my case? That's my goal.

Best,
Alex

Comment: cannot think of a way to do it via formula except `User Defined Formula` in `vba`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple UDF perhaps:

```
Public Function CellText(ByVal rng As Range) As String
    CellText = rng.Cells(1, 1).Text
End Function
```

[image]